# http.Post() from a gRPC server to an http server returns EOF error on a docker-compose setup

Tags: docker, http, go, error-handling, docker-compose

I have a gRPC server (`server`) written in Go that a Python gRPC client (`client`) talks to. The  server occasionally sends http post requests to a Go based http server (`sigsvc`). All of these instances run as docker instances spun up through docker-compose sharing the same docker network.

This is the section of code on `server` that creates and sends the http request:

```
b := new(bytes.Buffer)
txbytes, err := json.Marshal(tx)
if err != nil {
    log.WithError(err).Error("failed to marshal transaction")
    return nil, err
}
b.Write(txbytes)

resp, err := http.Post(sigsvc.signerURL, "application/json; charset=utf-8", b)
if err != nil {
    log.WithError(err).Errorf("error signing transaction with signer %s", sigsvc.signerURL)
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

var signedTx types.Transaction
err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&signedTx)
if err != nil {
    log.WithError(err).Error("couldn't decode signed transaction")
    return nil, err
}
```

`sigsvc.signerURL` maps to something like `http://signer:6666/sign` which is the endpoint on the http signer service that handles the request.
`signer` refers to the service name listed on a `docker-compose.yml` specification.

This is how the handler looks like on `sigsvc`:

```
func (sv *SignerSv) handleSignTx() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Info("request received to sign transaction")
        dump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, fmt.Sprint(err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
        log.Debugf("%q", dump)

        if r.Body == nil {
            log.Error("request body missing")
            http.Error(w, "Please send a request body", 400)
            return
        }

        log.Debugf("request body: %v", r.Body)

        var tx types.Transaction
        err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&tx)
        if err != nil {
            log.WithError(err).Error("failed to unmarshal transaction")
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
            return
        }

        log.WithFields(log.Fields{
            "txhash":   tx.Hash().Hex(),
            "nonce":    tx.Nonce(),
            "to":       tx.To().Hex(),
            "data":     tx.Data(),
            "gasLimit": tx.Gas(),
            "gasPrice": tx.GasPrice(),
            "value":    tx.Value(),
        }).Debug("Decoded transaction from request body")
```

Both the request and request body are dumped successfully by the debug logs. However, apparently the line decoding the request body to the `transaction` type is never executed, since no error or decoded transaction logs are logged.

On `server`, I keep getting the following error:
`error="Post http://signer:6666/sign: EOF"`

This is how the request is logged on `sigsvc`:

```
msg="\"POST /sign HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost: signer:6666\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\nAccept-Encoding: gzip\\r\\nConnection: close\\r\\nContent-Length: 10708\\r\\nUser-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1\\r\\n\\r\\n{\\\"nonce\\\":\\\"0x0\\\",\\\"gasPrice\\\":\\\"0x2540be400\\\",\\\"gas\\\":\\\"0x15c285\\\",\\\"to\\\":null,\\\"value\\\":\\\"0x0\\\",\\\"input\\\":\\\"0x6080604055",\\\"v\\\":\\\"0x0\\\",\\\"r\\\":\\\"0x0\\\",\\\"s\\\":\\\"0x0\\\",\\\"hash\\\":\\\"0xab55920fb3d490fc55ccd76a29dfb380f4f8a9e5d0bda4155a3b114fca26da0a\\\"}\"
```

I have tried reproducing this error on similar but simplified docker setups, but I have failed at that.

I'm trying to understand the following:

1. If there is anything wrong with this code that is being exposed due
   to a particular setup on docker?
2. Or, do I need to look at some docker setup specifics to debug the instances.

Comment: You are ignoring the error when marshaling to txbytes, which subsequently may well be nil or empty - which matches the EOF error message. Please check the error when marshaling.

Comment: Furthermore, the marshaling and write to the byte buffer could be done with a json.Encoder using b as target.

Comment: True. This version of the code ignores the error while marshalling to `txbytes`. Having said that, the marshalling is indeed successful in this case, since I get a request body on the http handler on `sigsvc`

Comment: I can confirm that I still get this error, after having added the error handling section for marshalling to `txbytes`.

Comment: I would try two things before looking into Docker networking: 1) try reading the whole body first, and then using `json.Unmarshal` instead of a decoder, 2) try it without calling `DumpRequest`

Comment: @BurakSerdar Could you explain why you suggest that? I basically run _everything_ in docker (even taskjuggler), and did not run into any problem.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg are you talking about my suggestion to look into Docker networking? Because of #2 in the original post. I meant to say "before looking into Docker, I'd try these things".

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've been able to debug what was causing this and have posted an answer. Also I have adopted the approach of reading the request or response body first and then using `json.Unmarshal()` instead of using `json.NewDecoder()`

Comment: @BurakSerdar I was curious if you had something specific in mind when it came to docker... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the way the http handler code was logging the `to` field in this `logrus` call.

```
log.WithFields(log.Fields{
    "txhash":   tx.Hash().Hex(),
    "nonce":    tx.Nonce(),
    "to":       tx.To().Hex(),
    "data":     tx.Data(),
    "gasLimit": tx.Gas(),
    "gasPrice": tx.GasPrice(),
    "value":    tx.Value(),
}).Debug("Decoded transaction from request body")
```

Under specific circumstances, the `tx.To()` call returns `nil`, which implies calling `tx.To().Hex()` would lead to an error on account of trying to make a method call on a `nil` pointer. On the face of it, one would expect the `log.WithFields()` call to error out or panic, but instead the handler silently closes connection with the client side getting an EOF response.